# Can information gain be negative?

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree

It's so weird about my quiz.{(200+/300-)->((50+/50-),(250-,150+))}, aftet calculation the IG is negative. Can some one explain why?

Answer (score 0):

After I researched some other questions, I think I got some idea. Some people say information gain cannot be negative, but actually it can be, depends on which feature you choose to split. I found a paper,http://compbio.umbc.edu/Documents/Negative_information.pdf, which shows some protein can influence the understanding of genomic composition, since protein are so messy. If we use some messy feature to build our tree, the information gain would be negative, since imagine, in the real world, if we want to make a decision, some features can make us hesitate. If we use this kind of features to make decision, the result would be more uncertain. Forgiving my poor English...

the example I've given is actually positive...my mistake, sorry about that.